# Abort a WCF connection

Tags: c#, wcf

Is there a way to stop a remote connection?

In more detail if a WCF connection is created using the ChannelFactory

```
var aChannelFactory = new ChannelFactory<ISomeService>(aBinding, aEndpoint);
```

and the connection is used via GSM, it makes sense to enlarge timeouts so that

```
aChannelFactory.CreateChannel();
```

has the possibility to connect to the remote site.

Now the problem is that a user may have the wish to stop the creation of a connection (Abort a getting connencted window, only use offline part of a programm).

But how is this possible?

The CreateChannel-call is synchronous.

Even if it is wrapped in a thread, nowadays Thread.Abort should not be used.

Is there any way to stop the creation of a channel automatically?

Or must it be "faked" to a user, so that the connection still is running until its timeout (or success) even is user decided to work temporarely offline?

Comment: may be this helps you http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/74129/The-Proper-Use-and-Disposal-of-WCF-Channels-or-Com

Comment: Are you trying to abort a request after it has been sent or are you trying to stop the user from being able to send future requests?

Comment: @KevinHolditch abort the request while its being sent.

Comment: A channel doesn't strictly _open_ as soon as it's created anyway. You call `Open` or use it then it does, so you can `Close` or `Abort` it too.

Comment: You can called abort on the channel which will close it down immediately but realise that obviously if data has already been sent then it's gone there's no way to recall it.

Comment: @GrantThomas thanks, that was the misunderstanding. I was assuming that 'CreateConnection' opens the connection, not the first call. I already had a pattern like "try{aClient = aChannelFactory.CreateChannel();}catch (Exception){if (aClient != null{((ICommunicationObject)aClient).Abort();}throw;}" but was just not aware that "CreateChannel" does not open the channel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Grant Thomas stated it is not necessary to abort the connection.